# How to smoothly go back to the first fragment on backpress

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am using navigation drawer in my app, each item in the drawer starts a fragment. If a fragment is in view, and the back button is pressed I want the activity to start the first fragment.

To expatiate, If I am looking at **AbtFragment** or **ContaFragment** and the back button is pressed, I want the activity to start or go back to **HomeFragment**.

**Part of my Activity**

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        id = item.getItemId();

        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.menu_home) {
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
        }

        if (id == R.id.about_blog) {
            fragment = new AbtFragment();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contri) {
            fragment = new ContFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
            fragment = new ContaFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_privy) {
            fragment = new PageFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_advert) {
            fragment = new PageFragment();

        }

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "visible_fragment");
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() >= 1) {
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.menu_home);
                navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.menu_home, 0);
            }

        }
```

From `onBackPressed`, I am checking for the number of fragment in backstack and then starting **HomeFragment** if it's greater than or equals to one, but this is not working properly. 
For example, If I start **AbtFragment**, and then **ContFragment**, and I press the back button, **AbtFragment** will first flicker on the screen before  **HomeFragment** will be shown.

Please, how do I correct this?

**Note** : **HomeFragment** is the default frgament hence it's started by default when the activity is launched.

Comment: addToBasckStack(). add the HomeFragment below your fragmentManager.replace() code

Comment: @RusheelJain: I don't understand you.

Answer (score 0):

example

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { 

NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 //set initial fragment to 'new' instead 
 addFragment(new NewFragment(), true); 

 //Set the toolbar
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 

 //Set navigation drawer
 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
 drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
 toggle.syncState();
 navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); 
}

@Override public void onBackPressed() {
  DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

  if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); } 
  else { 
  //put your alert dialog code here //
   if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) ...
  }
} 

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody") 
@Override 
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

// Handle navigation view item clicks here. 
int id = item.getItemId(); 
// Replace these with your own menu items 
 switch (id) { 
    case R.id.nav_start: 
      addFragment(new StartFragment(), true);
      break;
    case R.id.nav_save: 
      addFragment(new SaveFragment(), true);
      break; 
    case R.id.nav_raw: 
      addFragment(new RawFragment(), true);
      break; 
    case R.id.nav_gyroscope: 
      addFragment(new GyroscopeFragment(), true); 
      break; 
 } 

 DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
 return true; 
 } 

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, Boolean addToBackStack) {
  if (fragment != null) {
   FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName()) .addToBackStack(null) .commit();

  } 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but please look at my code again, I am using `id` not `position` and I didn't understand what you mean by "where displayView() it is the view that you wish see"

Comment: "and then you define a method allowBackPressed with the logic to allow back pressed or not", can you pleassssssse,include this logic in the answer?

Comment: logic for example if it is null, if you want to allow the action or other implementation

Comment: Do you mean something like `if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() >= 1) {
                navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.menu_home);
                navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.menu_home, 0);
            }` ?

Comment: I am trying to help as best I can. I added an implementation. Try to adapt to your needs